# Expected number with of rounds until n guests receive their correct keys through a random process

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, stopping-times

A hotel worker mixed up n keys for n rooms. The n guests show up
together. The worker chooses a random permutation of the keys and gives each guest
one key. If a guest receives his key, he leaves. The worker repeats the process with the
remaining guests and remaining keys. How can I use the stopping theorem to calculate the expected
number of rounds after which all guests receive their key. As a first step, define $X_i$ as the
number of guests receiving their keys in the $i^{th}$ round. Show that:

$$E(X_i | X_1, X_2, ..., X_{i-1})=1$$

Comment: A solution was presented here with induction but I am wondering if I can use stopping theorem

Comment: Have you done the ‘show that’ portion? That much is a variant on the classic ‘hat check’ derangements problem.

Comment: This is not quite right.  If $X_1 + \ldots + X_{i-1} = s < n$, then at round $n$ you have $n-s$ guests and $n-s$ keys, and the conditional expectation of $X_i$ is $1$, just like at the start.  But obviously if
$X_1 + \ldots + X_{i-1} = n$, $X_{i}$ must be $0$ because there's nobody left to receive a key.

Comment: Perhaps this may be useful: https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-012-introduction-to-probability-spring-2018/part-i-the-fundamentals/the-hat-problem/